# System Error 1202 - Local device name has a remembered connection to another network resource

Tags: networking, windows-10, command-line, windows-10-v1607

I just updated my Windows 10 computer to Update 1607 (the Anniversary Update).  I now get the error in the title when doing the following:

1. From a cmd prompt: `runas /user:contoso\mwolfe /netonly cmd`
2. From this new cmd window: `net use g: \\fs\Sales`
3. From a new cmd prompt: `runas /user:contoso\mwolfe /netonly cmd`
4. From this second new cmd window: `net use g: \\fs\Operations`

   - This results in the following output:

     > System error 1202 has occurred.
     >
     > The local device name has a remembered connection to another network resource.

This has worked for me for years (since at least Windows 7) and for Windows 10 through Update 1511.  After installing Update 1607 it now fails.  Is this a bug in the Windows update or do I need to use a workaround?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm a software developer and consultant.  One of my large clients has a fairly typical network setup where different departments have the same drive letter mapped to different network shares.  I'm not a member of their domain, so I run into trust issues if I try to map the drives directly.  The easiest workaround is to use a `runas` cmd with the `/netonly` flag.  This has the added benefit of creating an isolated environment within the cmd window.  It has allowed me to have multiple cmd windows each with their own G: drive mapped to a different department.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all the cmd windows and starting over.

Comment: This seems to have been a temporary issue.  I closed every cmd window then tried to reproduce it and the problem disappeared.  At this point I will assume it was a fluke and move on.  I would have tried this first except I had just updated to Win 10 v1607.  This was the very first time I tried this on update 1607 so I immediately assumed that was the culprit.  I still think it must have *something* to do with it.  This was the first time in *seven years* of using this on an almost daily basis that I saw this error.  It's got to be more than mere coincidence, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I tried restarting the computer, the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error occurred in the ISE when you have the ***same*** file opened in two tabs.

Hope this helps!

Jon